# Таблица с правами доступа для редактирования строки

Tags: html, sql, wordpress, table

Здравствуйте! У меня такой, вопрос как сделать таблицу с правами доступа к строке?
Например есть таблица на сайте, и пользователь может редактировать только свою строку. Сайт сделан на wordpress, пытался найти плагины, но не нашёл. Может посоветуете какие нибудь плагины или коды. Так как сам только начинающий. За ранее спасибо!

Comment: *Например есть таблица на сайте, и пользователь может редактировать только свою строку.* Ну добавьте в структуру поле идентификатора создателя записи, и при выводе на экран либо обновлении контролируйте соответствие.

Comment: А можете более подробно описать? Так как я понял абсолютно ничего.

Comment: В таблицу добавляете поле (скажем, `owner_id`), куда записываете идентификатор создателя записи (скажем, логин). И соответственно во все запросы добавляете условие контроля соответствия, скажем `WHERE ... AND owner_id = @current_login`. Если текущий логин не совпадает с логином владельца - запись не будет обновлена.

Comment: А в сайт, это, скорей всего, надо будет ввести через php? И через sql запросы на базу данных контролировать.

Comment: Не знаю, наверное. Вам реализовывать - Вам и флаг в руки.